# Emacs: is there a debug mode I can check where the value of a variable is changed?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a debug mode I can check where (which line in which file) the value of a variable is changed in Emacs?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such feature.  You're likely out of luck and need to resort to other means of finding out.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are out of luck.
However, not all is quite lost.

### Global Variable

With Common Lisp you could use
[`define-symbol-macro`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_1.htm),
but Emacs Lisp does not have it.

You need to eval

```
(defun my-func-name ()
  my-var-name)
```

and

```
(defsetf my-func-name (val)
  (warn "my-var-name=%s" val) ; or `error'
  (setq my-var-name val))
```

Then you have to search and replace `my-var-name` with `(my-func-name)` in the
sources, also replacing `(setq my-var-name ...)` with `(setf
(my-func-name) ...)` and recompile and reload the sources.

### Local Variable

Replace `let` with [`symbol-macrolet`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Macro-Bindings.html).

Answer (score 0):

in Emacs 26.1 do `M-x debug-watch <variable> RET`

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27962/tracking-down-a-write-to-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Debugging.html

> Command: debug-on-variable-change variable ¶
>
> This function arranges for the debugger to be called whenever
> variable is modified.
>
> ```
> It is implemented using the watchpoint mechanism, so it inherits the same characteristics and limitations: all aliases of variable will
> ```
>
> be watched together, only dynamic variables can be watched, and
> changes to the objects referenced by variables are not detected. For
> details, see Running a function when a variable is changed..